# Nested IF with MATCH does not work as expected

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

Does anyone know why only first half of this formula works? It only returns values that match first criteria and puts #N/A for all others. If I use each IF separately(i.e. in separate columns) then I am getting result for each of these.

```
=IF(MATCH(L2,red,0),"Red",IF(MATCH(L2,white,0),"White",IF(MATCH(L2,green,0),"Green",IF(MATCH(L2,black,0),"Black",IF(MATCH(L2,float,0),"Float","staff not found")))))
```

I am hoping to use conditional formatting distinguish staff the day each person works on. Red, white, black float, and green in the formula are basically just an range of names consisting of about 12 entries each.

Comment: wrap all your MATCH in ISNUMBER: `ISNUMBER(MATCH(L2,red,0))` If the match is not found it returns an error and the IF does not know how to handle them as it is neither TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked like a charm